# Android Kotlin - registerForActivityResult inside Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I tried:

```
val getUpdates = (context as Activity).registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {

    }
}
```

inside RecyclerView and get: `Unresolved reference: registerForActivityResult`

Is it not possible inside RecyclerView?

Comment: `registerForActivityResult()` is not a function on `Activity`. That is on `ComponentActivity`. I suspect that calling `registerForActivityResult()` from inside a `RecyclerView.Adapter` or `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` is not a good idea, though. Pass the event up to the activity or fragment hosting the `RecyclerView` and have it call `registerForActivityResult()`.

Comment: Well this sucks because it would reduce the code since this recyclerview adapter is used by 3 activities. Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare I just tried ComponentActivity instead of Activity and it works! Can you explain why it's a bad idea please?

Comment: I am concerned that you will make unfortunate assumptions about what you can do in that callback lambda expression. The whole `ActivityResultContract` system is rather fragile. For example, quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result), "You must always call `registerForActivityResult()` in the same order for each creation of your fragment or activity to ensure that the inflight results are delivered to the correct callback." That may be difficult to accomplish if you are not doing that directly in the activity or fragment.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll try to use for each item in RecyclerView and see if it will cause trouble, if it will I'll give feedback, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're attempting to do will result in a crash. The result callback must be registered at Activity creation (ie as a field/variable of the Activity)

> the callback must be unconditionally registered every time your activity is created, even if the logic of launching the other activity only happens based on user input or other business logic.

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register) for more details

Comment: But (context as ComponentActivity).registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) inside RecyclerView and nothing in Activity works? Am I just lucky with the device and Android API level and shouldn't keep it?

Comment: Ok for what ever reason it's not working when it's inside a function in RecyclerView but just as a variable. Well looks like it's fragile just like CommonsWare said and I have to use the old method even if it's deprecated. Android is such a pile of crap xD

Comment: Yep it should be a variable, the docs says it in a not so understandable way ("the callback must be unconditionally registered every time your activity is created")

Comment: I think it depends on where you initialize the adapter right?
If you initialize the adapter when the activity is being created, i supposed it will be fine.