# Android Crash - kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException MainActivity.getAdapterGallery

Tags: android

In the google play console I see that many users with only latest devices and Android 11 have this crash:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException
de.xxx.blabla.MainActivity.getAdapterGallery
```

I don't even have any class/method that is called `getAdapterGallery`

The tack trace is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4864)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4901)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute (ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:176)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2307)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8512)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1139)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:5506)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4851)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4901)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute (ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:176)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2307)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8512)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1139)
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: 
  at de.xxx.blabla.MainActivity.getAdapterGallery (MainActivity.java:7)
  at de.xxx.blabla.MainActivity.onActivityResult (MainActivity.java)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult (Activity.java:8541)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:5499)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4851)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4901)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute (ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:176)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2307)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8512)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1139)


EDIT:
```

This is what I have in onActivityResult:

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)

    if(requestCode == 777 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        if(data.hasExtra("commentCountChanged")) {
            val json = JSONObject(data.getStringExtra("commentCountChanged")!!)

            val memeID = json.getLong("memeID")
            val commentCount = json.getInt("commentCount")

            for (i in 0 until adapterMemes.memes.size) {
                if (adapterMemes.memes[i].id == memeID) {

                    adapterMemes.memes[i].commentcount = commentCount

                    val viewHolder = recyclerViewMemes.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as RecyclerView.ViewHolder

                    if (commentCount == 0) {
                        viewHolder.itemView.memeCommentsCount.text = "\u25CF"
                        viewHolder.itemView.memeCommentsCount.setTextSize(
                            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
                            8f
                        )
                    } else {
                        viewHolder.itemView.memeCommentsCount.text =
                            commentCount.toString()
                        viewHolder.itemView.memeCommentsCount.setTextSize(
                            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
                            16f
                        )
                    }

                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if(data.hasExtra("list")) {
            val updatedMemes = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Memes>("list") as ArrayList<Memes>

            val finalMemes: MutableList<Memes> = mutableListOf()
            for(i in 0 until updatedMemes.size){
                if(updatedMemes[i].title != "show_ad_break"){
                    finalMemes.add(updatedMemes[i])
                }
            }

            adapterGallery.memes = finalMemes
            adapterGallery.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an `onActivityResult()` implementation in `MainActivity`? If so, what does it contain?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I have, check out my edit, but I can't use the new alternative to onActivityResult from RecyclerView because Android is a piece of garbage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68231596/android-kotlin-registerforactivityresult-inside-recyclerview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't even have any class/method that is called getAdapterGallery

Yes, you do. You have a Kotlin property named `adapterGallery`, as you can see in your code:

```kotlin
            adapterGallery.memes = finalMemes
            adapterGallery.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

A Kotlin property, in terms of the JVM implementation, consists of a Java field plus a getter and setter pair. The getter for a property named `adapterGallery` is `getAdapterGallery()`.

So, based on the error message, you have defined `adapterGallery` as a `lateinit var`, and it has not been populated yet by the time you reach the code in `onActivityResult()` that references `adapterGallery`. For example, this error can happen if:

- The user navigates to whatever activity is returning a result to you
- The user leaves your app (e.g., system HOME navigation, switching to another task, responding to a notification, responding to an incoming phone call)
- While your app is in the background, Android terminates your process to free up system RAM, because your user has a low-end phone with limited RAM but also has a bunch of busy apps
- The user returns to your app, within 30 minutes of having left it, so Android returns the user to the activity they had last been on, to try to preserve the illusion that your app had been around all that time, despite its process having been terminated
- The user does something in that activity to return to the one that had called `startActivityForResult()`, which had not existed in this process, and Android calls `onActivityResult()` before you got a chance to set up your UI

In a modern Android app architecture, `onActivityResult()` would not be manipulating any widgets or objects tightly coupled to those widgets (such as a `RecyclerView.Adapter`). Instead, `onActivityResult()` would update some state holder (e.g., a `ViewModel`), which would then emit some new results (e.g., a view-state) using a reactive API (e.g., `LiveData`). Then, so long as your code that observes that reactive API does so only after your widgets are ready to use the data, you can avoid this sort of crash.

Another approach would be to try to eliminate `onActivityResult()` in the first place. In modern Android app development, we try to use few activities, with screens implemented as fragments (or composables). Your code in `onActivityResult()` suggests that you are responding to some result from some other activity of yours. Perhaps you should replace those two activities with one activity, updating the screen in other ways (fragments, composables, toggling view visibility, etc.).

These more modern techniques are covered in many books and courses on Android app development. Focus on ones written or updated in the past three years.

Whether you update your app to use modern recommended practices or not, you need to ensure that you do not try manipulating a `lateinit var` that has not yet been initialized.

Comment: wow this is more informative than I could expect. thanks!

Comment: Would if(this::adapterGallery.isInitialized){} be sufficient until I upgrade to proper techniques? I need to fix this error pretty fast because I'm receiving bad reviews

Comment: @EduardUnruh: That would avoid the crash. However, whatever work you are doing there will be skipped if `adapterGallery` is uninitialized, and I do not know how big a problem that will be for your app.

Comment: Ok thanks again! That will do until I improve the code